# Adding cloud-contracts dependency breaks nebula.release plugin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-contract, netflix-nebula-plugins

I'm encountering a weird error, I want to use the `nebula.release` plugin in Gradle. I'fe had success adding it both of the following ways:

```
plugins {
    id 'nebula.release' version '6.3.5'
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-release-plugin:6.3.4'
}
apply plugin: 'nebula.release'
```

However, no matter what, when I add the following classpath line for `spring-cloud-contracts`:

```
classpath "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE"
```

It gives me the following error:

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'nebula.release', version: '6.3.5']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'nebula.release']
   > No signature of method: org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.getRef() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [HEAD]
     Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), getFS(), grep(), exactRef(java.lang.String), findRef(java.lang.String), getAllRefs()
```

I'm not sure at all why adding this one dependency breaks so many things, any help would be great!

Comment: Most likely you have mismatch in gradle / groovy versions. Which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak same to me actually. I'm using gradle 5.1; nebula.release plugin in version 6.3.3; and spring cloud contract plugin in version 2.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: Do you have a sample that you could upload?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak sure. Reproduced it in this repo with github pipelines: https://github.com/athlan/spring-cloud-contract-nebula-example

Comment: Finally, resolved. Posted answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bump your Nebula plugin to later version for example to 15.1.0.

Sample project: https://github.com/athlan/spring-cloud-contract-nebula-example

Detailed description:

Spring Cloud Contract ships newer version of jgit library (in comparison to nebula version you referenced) where above mentioned method has been deprecated and in newer version finally removed.